# Double appendix in latex

Tags: chapters, appendix

Is there a reason why the appendix produces 2 titles?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\begin{document}

test 
\appendix 
\chapter{\textrm\bfseries Appendixtest2}\label{append}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I force the appendix title (using \chapter, not \section) to have this format:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) `\appendix`  does not produce any title, only change the `\chapter` behavior to print "Appendix A" instead of "Chapter 1."

(2) There are only one title, produced by `\chapter`, With `\chaptertitlename` (Appendix) and `\thechapter` (A) in one line, and the chapter argument (Appendixtest2) in the other.

(3) you can force the format of chapter title with that `\titleformat` command  using the package using the package **`titlesec`**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\begin{document}
\appendix 
\chapter{The title of the appendix}
\end{document}
```

**But note that you are trying to force the default fomat to ... the default format!** So, you will not see any effect.

You can notice that it is really working using just any other format, for instance, only with one title in one line:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\appendix 
\chapter{The title of the appendix}
\end{document}
```

Or with two lines and more ...

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\hrule\bigskip\hfill\bfseries\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\appendix 
\chapter{The title of the appendix}
\end{document}
```

Or even is this way, a bit more tricky:

[image: mwe3]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large}{}{1em}{\bfseries #1 (\chaptertitlename\  \thechapter)}
\begin{document}
\appendix 
\chapter{The title of the appendix}
\end{document}
```